# JMeter recording request/sampler which I did not recorded deliberately

Tags: jmeter

- JMeter recording request/sampler which I did not record deliberately.

  While recording some request getting recorded even though I do not
  click on those link which is part of my app but not part of my test,
  How I can stop it by getting a recorded

  unnecessary requests like

/admin/login/get_session_id/

/admin/restaurant/deleteuser

/admin/restaurant/set_authority_exist

... and many more some are repeatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter "invent" anything, it just captures requests which are coming through its [Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

If the requests were captured by JMeter - then your browser has executed them in the background. Some requests are being triggered by JavaScript (like [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) calls) so it might be the case JMeter will be capturing the requests even if you don't touch anything because your application will refresh itself by loading new pieces of data periodically. For example open [Google Finance page](https://www.google.com/finance) and inspect network tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

If you don't really want these requests to be recorded and they are not supposed to be executed you can filter them out via "URL Patterns to Exclude" list of the "Requests Filtering" tab of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder:

[image]

However most probably these requests are being triggered by your browser and they're fired in parallel so you not only need to record them but you need to put them under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) to mimic browser-like network footprint.